# Is it possible to use cells in vba function in arrays place?

Tags: excel, vba, string, substring

I saw a function here that allowed me to identify substrings in a given string, however I don´t know how to use that function in a worksheet with cells I select. Here is the code:

```
Function IsInArray2(StringToBeFound As String, MyArray As Variant) As Boolean
IsInArray2 = False
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
    If LCase(StringToBeFound) Like LCase("*" & MyArray(i) & "*") Then
    IsInArray2 = True 'will match MyArray to any substring of StringToBeFound
    Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

I want to select a cell to define my "StringToBeFound" and a range to define "MyArray"

Any help gratefully appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
Function IsInArray2(StringToBeFound As String, MyArray As Range) As Boolean
IsInArray2 = False
dim cell as range
For each cell in myarray.cells
    If LCase(StringToBeFound) Like LCase("*" & cell.value & "*") Then
    IsInArray2 = True 'will match MyArray to any substring of StringToBeFound
    Exit Function
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Use: `IsInArray2 = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

The following would work:

```
Function IsInArray2(StringToBeFound As String, MyArray As Range) As Boolean
    IsInArray2 = Not (MyArray.Find(StringToBeFound) Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work as pretended :( But thank you!!

Comment: The crucial detail here is to use the `Find` method's `LookAt` argument's parameter `xlPart`: `.Find(StringToBeFound, , , xlPart)`. You should also firmly control the `LookIn` argument's parameter. If you choose `xlValues`, hidden cells of the range will not be checked leaving `xlFormulas` as the better choice (if there aren't formulas in the range): `.Find(StringToBeFound, , xlFormulas, xlPart)`.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 - when I tested this little function, it behaved exactly as I wanted - i.e. partial string match. I assumed this was the default if not specified?

Comment: No - if not specified it is set by the last find operation done, whether in code or in the UI. That's why you should always specify it.

Answer (score 0):

### IsInRange UDF

- Returns a boolean indicating whether a string (`StringToBeFound`) is contained in any of the cells of a range (`MyRange`).

```vb
Function IsInRange( _
    ByVal StringToBeFound As String, _
    ByVal MyRange As Range) _
As Boolean

    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = MyRange.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = MyRange.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If rCount * cCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = MyRange.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = MyRange.Value
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            If InStr(1, CStr(Data(r, c)), StringToBeFound, vbTextCompare) > 0 _
                Then IsInRange = True: Exit Function
        Next c
    Next r

End Function
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for returning the value in the next column instead of a boolean type. I´m sorry, it was my fault.